# Mongodb remove objects

Tags: mongodb

I have the following code:

Log.ts

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import ILog = require("./ILog");


interface ILogModel extends ILog, mongoose.Document { }

var logSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    date: Date,
});

var log = mongoose.model<ILogModel>("Log", logSchema);

export = log;
```

ILog.ts

```
interface ILog {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    date: Date;
};

export = ILog;
```

In my app I generate Logs with the following code:

```
                    var log = {
                        title: "tag",
                        description: "test",
                        date: Date.now()
                    };
                    Log.create(log, function (err: any, remote: any) {

                    });
```

But when I do `Log.remove( { })` nothing happens.

In `ROBO 3T` if I do `db.getCollection('logs').remove({})`
the log is cleared, but I don't understand how to do it in the app

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    Log.remove({}, function (err: any) {
                        if (err) return console.log("err", err);
                    });
```

did the trick